# Linksys' incoming log...do i have an intruder?

Tags: windows, security

My Linksys administration tab where logs are located shows a total of 12 incoming connection entries.
Some of these addresses say they're in china when i google them which exponentially increased my concern; the ports they list means they weren't video games, i know that, so what do i do now?

setup:

- gaming pc, Windows Server, wife's laptop, x360, xbone
- WAMP on gaming pc IIS8 on Windows Server (changed default MySQL root pw)
- Wordpress install on both with plugins(plugins the culprit?)
- all plugins installed via Wordpress admin from Wordpress.org on both Wordpress installations
- had a second Wordpress on port 8080.
- ddns via NO-IP forwarded to windows server from router

**log:**

- 114.232.18.30    80 (www)
- 117.86.122.5 8080 (webcache)
- 218.77.79.43 80 (www)
- 218.6.173.36 3306 (mysql)
- 222.186.15.95    3306 (mysql)
- 218.77.79.43 8080 (webcache)
- 61.147.107.109   3306 (mysql)
- 218.77.79.43 21 (ftp)
- 198.20.70.114    3306 (mysql)
- 60.173.11.151    8080 (webcache)
- 65.55.158.119    3074 (xbox)

i ran netstat -abf 5 for 3 minutes and i'm looking at a printout of the results right now, and realized i should've closed every service/site/program i could think of before logging as it's about 20+ pages printed out...i will edit+add any listing that i do not understand.

I want to see if it was a legitimate WordPress plugin or some other aspect of iis and/or apache and should not concern me. **I'll check Apache and IIS logs when i get home and paste anything that looks like information you could use to reach a decision**. Any additional information on where/what i need to look at would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the actual log?

Comment: @DanielB thanks for the reply. what you see above is the ridiculous ly uninformative log it gave me for incoming connections.

Comment: I see. Well, that’s not really helpful—though I doubt successful connection attempts would be logged. Do you have any port forwarding set up on your router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it, it's people doing a network scan, not intruding your network. They are poking your network to see if anything is open or vulnerable, and if not, they move on. As long as you don't have ports open and pointing to vulnerable services, there is no reason to be concerned.

Your home has a public IP, and anyone can reach out to it, but it doesn't mean that they can get into your network. They ports they are listing are to see if there are any public facing services, and if there are, they will try to attack them.

For example, they try to reach the mysql standard port to see if you have a mysql server running, and if you do, they will try to login, but as long as you don't have a mysql server running with that port open, you are safe.

To check if any of your ports are open, check to see if any of your ports are forwarded on your router, and see where they are forwarded to. If they are forwarded, find out what service is running on that port, and determine if it is a security risk depending on what is running on that port.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i thought that since the log said connection successful, that they were able to successfully gain access to my system? i should have understood that this meant they successfully connected...not successfully gained access to what's behind those ports. I had opened 80 and 8080 for wordpress...is there a way to see if they probed further and/or were able to access my network? i assume this is where Apache and IIS logs come into play (at work can't read them yet). none of the passwords are default.i thought mysql was setup for nonremote..i'll recheck.

Comment: Exactly, check your Apache/IIS logs to see what page they were trying to access (probably some wordpress default page). Check your Wordpress version and make sure you are up to date with all the security releases.

Comment: Also, if it successfully connected to your mysql port, you might want to consider closing that port unless you have a good reason to have it open. You shouldn't need an open port for a local copy of wordpress to access mysql. Making your DB web-facing is often a dangerous idea.

Comment: sorry for this side note..i dont wanna get another negative point..esp since this is my first post that received a true answer...but what did i do wrong to get the -2? i editted the capitalization errors in suggested edit, and thought my question was framed, precise, and showed i did my own work before asking the question.

Comment: Hard to say, I didn't downvote you, but the title "Home Network compromised" is a bit misleading but that's because you didn't understand the logs you were reading. People tend to dislike jumping to conclusions. A better title might be asking you for an explanation of the log, and then in the question ask if it is an intruder. Also some people downvote for questions that people think are "too simple", which this one could fall under for some voters.

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch...i figured it might be the title....i've always had a problem with titles and constantly change the title on posts a few times before i even post and still end up falling short.